# Gradle / Groovy Syntax and keywords

Tags: groovy, gradle

Being new to both Gradle and Groovy I find myself having a hard time understanding the syntax of a build.gradle script.

I understand (at least I think so) that build.gradle is plain groovy code used as DSL where the keywords are defined elsewhere.

Please explain what the different parts are. Taken from the Tutorial:

```
defaultTasks 'distribution'

task distribution << {
    println "We build the zip with version=$version"
}

task release(dependsOn: 'distribution') << {
    println 'We release now'
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(release)) {
        version = '1.0'
    } else {
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

e.g. I think I know *println* is a function. I know text in quotation marks is a string. I guess stuff in curly braces is a closure.
But what is `release`/`distribution`? Is it a string, too? Is it a parameter to a function `task`? And why can I use it in `hasTask(release)` without quotation marks?

So what exacly *is*: `defaultTasks`, `task`, `release`, `<<`, `gradle`, `whenReady`, `->`?

Bonus: is there a groovy way to find out myself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Comment: Jea. It's the same question. Same intention. (Even same confustion about "strings"). Technically the other one is the duplication since it's 8 month younger. But never mind. At least he/she got a helpful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you kind of shouldn't care. It's a DSL in which terms like "parameter to a function task" shouldn't bother you. What you should know is adding a new task is `task taskName`.

If you really want to dig in (e.g. for extending Gradle, implementing plugins, etc.) [Gradle DSL docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/) are your friends. From there, you can learn that [`task` is a method on `Project` object](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3atask%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Technically, the Gradle build language is a domain specific language (DSL) implemented using Groovy compile-time and runtime meta-programming. You can learn how to use the DSL (but not how it is implemented) in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I regard "don't care" not satisfying. I think understanding the underlying principles is fundamental in understanding how to use something. At least from a programmers standpoint. E.g. I don't want to remember that I have to use quotes *here* but not *there*, but I want to know that *this stuff* is a function declaration and therefor don't need them while *that stuff* takes a string argument while *that other stuff* takes a string but automatically converts ... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

> But what is release/*distribution*? Is it a string, too? Is it a parameter to a function task? And why can I use it in hasTask(release) without quotation marks?

Those are Strings in Gradle, but not in vanilla Groovy. This is mentioned in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264)

> So what exactly is: 'defaultTasks', 'task', '<<', 'gradle', 'whenReady', '->'?

Those are mostly methods or fields.
Fields:

- project.defaultTasks
- project.gradle

Methods:

- project.task()
- task.whenReady()
- task.leftShift()

`->` is core groovy syntax for closures.