# Gradle Task creation

Tags: groovy, gradle

**Problem**

In a build.gradle script I get that:

```
 task 'myTestStr', {}         // is the same as
 Project.task('myTestStr, {}) // <-- this
```

But I don't get what:

```
task myTest(){} //invokes on the Project instance?
```

I'm learning Gradle and Groovy coming from a Java background so I'm pretty sure I'm missing some groovy-ness that explains this magic.

**Additional Details**

Using Intellij to Find Declaration (Ctrl + b) over **myTest(){}** says that it invokes [TaskContainer#create(java.lang.String)](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#create%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It invokes exactly the same. If in a method declaration closure is the last argument it can be passed after the closing paren.

For instance [inject](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method:

```
assert 1*1*2*3*4 == [1,2,3,4].inject(1) { acc, val -> acc * val }
assert 1*1*2*3*4 == [1,2,3,4].inject(1, { acc, val -> acc * val })
```

Comment: Cool, I saw that in the groovy closure [docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures#Closures-ClosuresasMethodArguments). So is the myTest in myTest(){} casted to a String?

Comment: Yes, it is casted to string. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understing-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition/27584555#27584555 to get some details.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling someone had asked the same question but I couldn't figure out the right terms to search for it.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a bit different question. The answer under the link I provided explains gradle DSL internals. If the problem is solved, please accept.

Comment: That's fine I had a feeling that this kind of question would lead me down the rabbit hole, here we go :).