# How gradle dependencies work

Tags: gradle, dependencies

When I walk through the gradle dsl guide, I notice the DependencyHandler. It's delegated to closure when execute dependencies method. Just like 

`dependencies {
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
}`

The point I can't understand is why "compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'" caused the method "add(configurationName, dependencyNotation)" be invoked.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally Gradle uses Groovy's metaprogramming features, specifically [methodMissing](http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing), to implement this capability. You can see how this is done in the [`DependencyHandler`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/dependencies/DefaultDependencyHandler.java#L112-L130) implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it thoroughly now.