# what does this closure looking code in groovy means?

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures

I am experimenting with some gradle at a new project, and in its ***settings.gradle***, file I see these few lines that I am unable to make sense of as to what groovy structure or a language feature it is and what it does and how it works:

```
plugins {
  id "com.gradle.build-scan" version "1.12.1"
  id "cz.malohlava"     version "1.0.3"
}

buildScan {
  server = "some.host.com"
  publishAlways()
}
```

I was suspecting it was either a a ***closure*** or an ***interface*** of some sort, but could not make head or tail of it.

Any help in understanding following will be a great help:

- what it does?
- How plugins and buildScan works here from the language's perspective?

Comment: There are some existing questions which may help with understanding, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131860/how-gradle-dependencies-work

Answer (score 4):

From the language perspective, the closures are executed in the context of another objects than the build script. This is called delegation in Groovy.

http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegation_strategy

`plugin` delegates to https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html

`buildScan` delegates to Build Scan Plugin's extension object which configures the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some trickery here that I don't understand, particularly as I can't find either `plugins()` or `buildScan()` in the API docs. Nonetheless, the following is a reasonable reading of what the syntax means.

1. `plugins {}` and `buildScan {}` are both *methods* that take a closure (see other answers for explanation of this) as an argument.
2. Each closure has a *delegate* object of a particular type that's different depending on the method using the closure, i.e. the delegate of `plugins()` will be of a different type to the delegate of `buildScan()`
3. Within the closure, unqualified methods and properties will be executed against the delegate object. So for the `plugins {}` block, `id(...).version(...)` will be called against its delegate. For `buildScan {}`, you're setting the property `server` on the delegate and calling its `publishAlways()` method.

Honestly, I don't know how useful the above information is for using and understanding Gradle, but I think it's what you're asking for. Hope it helps!