# Gradle configuration/dependency syntax

Tags: gradle

I am struggling to understand the gradle groovy syntax for dependencies and what is going on behind the scenes. As a starter I don't see what is exactly happening in this code snippet ....

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
}
```

**What I (hope to) understand (please correct if I am wrong):**

- `dependecies` is a method of the `org.gradle.api.Project` interface /
        `org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject` class which expects a
        Closure to configure the dependencies of the project.
- `compile` is a `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration` which has been added by the `org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin`

**What I don't understand:**

- What exactly is happening by specifying `group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'` ?
- Does this invoke some magic method of the compile configuration object (if so, which one)?
- Are `group`, `name` and `version` named parameters of a method call or are they method calls themselves?
- Does this create a new `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency` instance which is added to the compile configuration?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle (like other tools built with Groovy) makes lots of use of `methodMissing(...)`: http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing

So what happens in the case of `dependencies` is that you invoke a method that does not exist. The method name is the name of the configuration, and its arguments are the dependency specification.

`methodMissing(...)` will be called and this will in turn call one of the `add(...)` methods of `DependencyHandler`: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html