# Which method in project is getting invoked when I define a task?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have defined a task in a gradle file as shown below:

```
task groupTherapy (dependsOn: yayGradle2) << {
    println 'This is not fun!'
}
```

I believe that below are the methods that get called when a task is defined:

```
Task    task(Map<String,?> args, String name)

Task    task(Map<String,?> args, String name, Closure configureClosure)

Task    task(String name)

Task    task(String name, Closure configureClosure)
```

Can you please explain me in my case which of these methods will get invoked? And help me understand why?

Comment: Forgot to mention  that I am new to gradle and groovy.

Comment: This is what you might be looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understing-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition/27584555#27584555

Comment: Thanks. That Helped. :)

Comment: but still I want to know , how the " dependsOn: yayGradle2 " gets interpreted ? is that also a AST transformation ? any idea Opal ?

Comment: This is just a `Map`.

Comment: In this particular case the first one will be invoked.

Comment: have you upvoted the answer I linked? May I add the asnwer to be accepted?

Comment: Hi Opal please add the answer I will accept it. One more thing , I understand that "dependsOn: yayGradle2"  will be passed as a Map, what about the name of the task ?

Comment: Here you are. The name will be extracted and passed as a `String` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition/27584555#27584555) you can find an answer that might be interesting. `dependsOn: yayGradle2` will be passed as an instance of `Map`. The name of the task will be extracted internally by gradle and passed as a name.