# How exactly is the task in gradle created?

Tags: gradle

I am wondering about the following pieces of Gradle scripts:

1. `task name`
2. `task 'name'`
3. `task name {...}`
4. `task 'name' {...}`

I am looking at the `Project` methods as well as `TaskContainer` methods, but it is not obvious how the `task ...` is transformed into a method call.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126369/which-method-in-project-is-getting-invoked-when-i-define-a-task/33610313#33610313) answer.

Comment: If you found it helpful, please upvote it.