# Understand Gradle-Groovy semantics

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am having a very hard time understanding the semantics of gradle scripts w.r.t how they are seen in groovy.

1) What does the following snippet mean?

```
task copy(type: Copy) {
   into "target"
   with baseSpec
}
```

As I understand it, it seems to me that task is instantiated with a named parameter "type" and it's value "Copy". I have no idea what is "into", "with". Are they parameters of the task class? BTW, Is task a class or interface?

2) What is a "script block"? Is it a closure?
3) What is an "Action"? Are they also closures or objects of interface instantiated with anonymous class?

Basically, I am lost how to put all of this together as a plain groovy ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Answer (score 4):

Groovy is a powerful language for building DSL (Domain Specific Language). Gradle use this as many others libraries.

It's based on several properties of Groovy

- Parenthesis are optionals

  ```
  fun("myparameter")
  fun "myparameter"
  ```
- You can have named parameters on a method

  ```
  fun prop:'value', otherprop:'othervalue'
  fun([prop:'value', otherprop:'othervalue'])
  ```
- If the last parameters of a method is a closure, it can be written outside the method call

  ```
  fun(prop:'value') {
    //..closure call
  }
  fun([prop:'value'], { /*closure*/ })
  ```
- You can get/set any property or invoke any method on a groovy object :  you can add behavior dynamically, through `missingMethod`, `missingProperty`, `getProperty` or `setProperty`, ..

  ```
  object.somefun "42"
  object.missingMethod("somefun", ["42"])
  ```
- In a closure, you have a special object, called delegate. it can be setted at runtime, and any non-local property or method invocation can be delegated to this delegate

  ```
  def fun = { copy "this_file" }
  def fun = { delegate.copy("this_file") }
  ```

  See [this documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html) or the Builder pattern

with this properties, your script can be written (it's not really true because of AST transformation..) :

```
task(copy([type: Copy], { it -> 
  delegate.into("target")
  delegate.with(baseSpec)
}))
```

`delegate` is an object which implement `missingMethod`, and generate objects based on the method call and the context.

a more complexe script :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
    }
}
```

is equivalent to :

```
buildscript({ it -> 
  delegate.repositories({delegate.mavenCentral()})
  delegate.dependencies({delegate.classpath([group:'commons-codec', name:'commons-codec', version:'1.2'])})
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. Can you please breakdown that syntactically?

Comment: task(copy([type: Copy], { it -> 
  delegate.into("target")
  delegate.with(baseSpec)
}))