# Add sourcesJar task to custom Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build-process, gradle-plugin

My company recently wrote gradle plugin for vanilla configuration (repositories, common dependencies across projects, etc).  Overall, this has greatly simplified our build process and uncovered a few inconsistencies across projects.  We recently tried to add a `sourcesJar` task to the plugin and it's not working.

Here's the broken plugin:

```
package com.mycompany.plugins

import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar

class OurJavaPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    void apply(Project project) {

        def date = com.mycompany.util.UtilityFunctions.getDate()

        project.configure(project) {
            println('Applying Java properties to: ' + project.name)

            apply plugin: 'java'
            apply plugin: 'maven'
            apply plugin: 'idea'
            apply plugin: 'eclipse'

            version = date

            // Use the local repos
            repositories {
                maven {
                    url "$externalDependenciesRepo"
                }
                maven {
                    url "$internalDependenciesRepo"
                }
            }

            uploadArchives {
                repositories {
                    mavenDeployer {
                        // Deploy to internal repo
                        repository(url: "$internalDependenciesRepo")
                    }
                }
            }

            // Common dependencies
            dependencies {
                compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version:'1.2.17'
                compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version:'1.6.6'
                compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version:'1.6.6'
                testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"
            }

            eclipse.project {
              natures 'org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature'
            }

            task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
                classifier = 'sources'
                from sourceSets.main.allSource
            }

            artifacts {
                archives sourcesJar
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This plugin works great, except for the `sourcesJar`.  When I add that into the mix (and compile/deploy to our local repo) I get this error when I try to build a project that uses the plugin:

```
$ gradle :myProject:clean -x Test
Applying Java properties to: myProject

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\me\Documents\code\root\myProject\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myProject'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'customjava']
   > Could not find method sourcesJar() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar, dependsOn=task ':analytics-isr:classes'}, com.mycompany.plugins.OurJavaPlugin $_apply_closure1$_closure6@4c1d59cd] on project ':myProject'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.352 secs
```

Comment: Isn't it working when you add the code as is? What's happening?

Comment: if I put the code inside the .configure if gives me an error.  I will update with the error as soon as I can.

Comment: I updated the question to include the error messages

Comment: Could you please grant me the bounty you offered? It does not happen automatically :)

Comment: Sorry, was out of town by the time SO would allow me to grant it.  +200 to you, and a heartfelt "Thanks!" from my team.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a task in `build.gradle` script one (out of 4) of `task` method is called - you can see the first one [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task-java.util.Map-java.lang.String-). As you can also see none of these methods matches the DSL - with which - you define a task in `build.gradle`. Why? Because before execution every `build.gradle` is evaluated to *translate* the DSL to appropriate methods invocations. For further details please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition) question.

The mentioned mechanism does not work in a custom plugin - here the code is interpreted *as is* without *translating* it. As you can see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) there's no `sourcesJar` method defined on `Project` class. To create a task inside a plugin you need to invoke on of the mentioned `task` methods, e.g.:

```
task('sourcesJar', type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
   classifier = 'sources'
   from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
```

which invokes exactly [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.String,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method (I know the arguments order is different but this is how groovy works - trust me).

Also you don't need `project.configure(project) {...}`, `project.with {...}` will be enough.