# gradle task definition syntax

Tags: gradle, groovy

gradle docs say that the way I declare task in my build.gradle file should be

```
task greeting(type: GreetingTask) {
    greeting = 'greetings from GreetingTask'
}
```

can anybody explain to me what happens here in terms of groovy syntax?
I know that  `{}` block is the closure and it can be passed as a parameter to the function but I still don't get what's happening here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `task` keyword is a gradle-specific stuff. It's not standard groovy, but something added by gradle using an AST transformation, in order to make the DSL simpler. It's basically equivalent to

```
project.tasks.create([name: 'greeting', type: GreetingTask]) { ... }
```

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-translate-task-keyword-in-dsl-into-groovy-call/7243

Comment: what does it mean when the closure is following function call ?@JB Nizet

Comment: That's standard groovy syntax. It's equivalent to having the closure as last argument.

Comment: Is there any general way of telling what is gradle-specific and what is groovy-specific without knowing everything about everything first?