# What does Gradle compile files, and coppile fileTree works

Tags: gradle, groovy

This is working gradle build script code:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("dir/libs", "dir/libs2")
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar")
}
```

As far as I understand it,

**dependencies** is a method that takes a closure, sets it's delegate property to DependencyHandler object and execute it.

**compile** is a Configuration object belonging to project

But what are **files** and **fileTree**?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#fileTree-java.util.Map-, https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: additional link: see Gradle Project DSL documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html .

Comment: Buy how is the collection -- (ConfigurableFileCollection) --, that is returned by files,  applied to compile object?
It does't look like an assignment nor method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to know is that Gradle uses AST for the `dependecies` closure syntax [this answer here does a good job of explaining what AST is.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584555/3505609)

I'll talk about the above code snippet, you are right about the block of code being delegated to the `DependencyHandler`, the line
is defined [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) as

> To declare a specific dependency for a configuration you can use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>      configurationName dependencyNotation1, dependencyNotation2, ...
>  }
> ```

The important thing to note here is the above code is **syntax** provided by Gradle to make code clean and terse. You could as well use the method [`DependencyHandler.add(String,Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)
For example

```
dependencies {
          add('compile', fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "*.jar"))
  }
```

As compared to the above syntax, the top syntax allows you to add multiple dependencies in a single statement and is a lot more cleaner.

`fileTree()`, `files()` etc are methods defined in `Project`. From `DependencyHandler.add(String,Object)`, the second argument is of type `Object`, as such the method as well as the dependency syntax can accept a number of type of dependencies like `ProjectDependency`, other  `Configuration`s and  `FileCollection` and its sub types as you mentioned the `ConfigurableFileCollection`.