# Gradle tasks definition

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

These three forms to define a task in build.gradle seem identical. All of them call `org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject#task(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure)`, but really I can't understand how the second and the third one can work.

```
def myAction = {t -> println "${t.name} [${t.class.name}]"}

task('myTaskA') {task ->
    group = 'MyTasks'
    description = name
    doLast myAction
}

task myTaskB {task ->
    group = 'MyTasks'
    description = name
    doLast myAction
}

task myTaskC() {task ->
    group = 'MyTasks'
    description = name
    doLast myAction
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584555/6509

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that all these forms are discouraged. The recommended way to define a custom task is `tasks.register("myTask") { ... }`, which also doesn't look as magical as the older forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Comment: @BjørnVester - where (link/resource) did you get the information from that tasks.register("..."){...} is recommended and the other task definition forms are discouraged?

Comment: @BjørnVester - I've myself answered my question see below.

Answer (score 1):

[Task Configuration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html): As of Gradle 5.1, it is recommend that the configuration avoidance APIs are used whenever tasks are created by custom plugins. The Configuration Avoidance API will co-exists with the existing APIs that will be replaced with the usual deprecation process over several major releases. In a nutshell, the API allows builds to avoid the cost of creating and configuring tasks during Gradle’s configuration phase when those tasks will never be executed, which can have a significant impact on total configuration time.

Instead of: “`task ... {…}`”, “`task ... << {…}`”, “`task('...') {…}`”, etc. use “**`tasks.register('...') {…}`**” API.