# What is the dependencies between tasks from the groovy point of view?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Consider the following piece of the build script:

```
task compile(dependsOn: 'resources') << {
    if (classesDir.isDirectory()) {
        println 'The class directory exists. I can operate'
    }
}
```

The first thought that popped into my head was that `dependsOn: 'resources'` is just "named parameter" like we use when we `apply plugin: 'java'` that is converted to a map afterwards. But It's not true, because

```
task compile([dependsOn: 'resources']) << {
    //etc
}
```

doesn't work. Error that was printed:

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [{dependsOn=resources}]
```

but `apply ([plugin: 'java'])` works fine. So what is that, then?

Comment: reading this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264/how-to-interpret-gradle-dsl