# Why those two task definition syntaxes equivalent?

Tags: groovy, gradle

Can you explain why those two task definitions in Gradle are equivalent?

```
task(type: Copy, 'myTask')
```

And

```
task myTask(type: Copy)
```

Is it some Groovy magic syntax thingy that I'm not familiar with, or actually a Gradle preprocessing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret Gradle DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264/how-to-interpret-gradle-dsl)

Comment: I think it's [this piece of code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer.java#L55-L81)

Comment: @Javier92 Cool! Thanks man

Comment: @Javier92 How did you find that out by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle seems to use build script transformers, which are executed during the buildscript compilation phase.

[Here's the transformer](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer.java#L55-L81) you're looking for.

[Here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/BuildScriptTransformer.java) is a list of transformations.