# why can quotes be left out in names of gradle tasks

Tags: gradle, groovy, build-tools

I don't understand why we don't need to add quotes to the name of gradle task when we declare it
like:

```
task hello (type : DefaultTask) {
}
```

I've tried in a groovy project and found that it's illegal, how gradle makes it works.
And I don't understand the expression above neither, why we can add `(type : DefaultTask)`, how can we analyze it with groovy grammar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example in a GroovyConsole runnable form, you can define a bit of code thusly:

```
// Set the base class for our DSL

@BaseScript(MyDSL)
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

// Something to deal with people
class Person { 
    String name
    Closure method
    String toString() { "$name" }
    Person(String name, Closure cl) {
        this.name = name
        this.method = cl
        this.method.delegate = this
    }
    def greet(String greeting) {
        println "$greeting $name"
    }
}

//  and our base DSL class

abstract class MyDSL extends Script {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        return new Person(name, args[0])
    }

    def person(Person p) {
        p.method(p)
    }
}

// Then our actual script

person tim {
    greet 'Hello'
}
```

So when the script at the bottom is executed, it prints `Hello tim` to stdout

But David's answer is the correct one, this is just for example

[See also here in the documentation for Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html)

Answer (score 1):

A Gradle build script is a Groovy DSL application. By careful use of "methodMissing" and "propertyMissing" methods, all magic is possible.

I don't remember the exact mechanism around "task ".  I think this was asked in the Gradle forum (probably more than once).

Comment: Mechanism commented on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that make the magic possible and legal.

```
// DSL class - Gradle Task
class Task {

    def name;
}

// DSL class - Gradle Project
class Project {

    List<Task> tasks = [];


    def methodMissing(String name, def args) {
        if(name == "task"){
            Task t = new Task(name:args[0])
            tasks << t
        }
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        name
    }
}

// gradle build script
def buildScript = {

    task myTask

    println tasks[0].name

}

buildScript.delegate = new Project()

// calling the script will print out "myTask"

buildScript()
```