# Full syntax for Gradle task declaration

Tags: gradle, groovy, build

I'm currently learning how to use Gradle `task` API to build java projects.

I understand that

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

is the shorthand syntax for

```
project.apply(['plugin': 'java'])
```

I find the full syntax a bit more intuitive and easier to understand

So, what is the **FULL** syntax for

```
task helloWorld {
    doLast {
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670201/why-we-dont-need-to-add-quotes-to-the-name-of-gradle-task-when-we-declare-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is eventual shorthand for:

```
// real syntax is project.task("helloWorld", {...}), but will be excuted like below
project.taskContainer.create("helloWorld").configure({ Task task ->
   task.doLast({ Task it -> 
        println("hello world")
    });
});
```

So a task is created then configured with closures that will run in given build phases.

In general in Gradle it is often helpful to add the input types to closures, but short of using a debugger it is often difficult to know, the documentation stays mostly silent on that to encourage a "declarative" style usage.

Comment: `it` in that situation is the task (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/AbstractTask.java#L446).  And it will just be `println("hello world")`, not `it.println...` as println is not a method on Task

Comment: @tim_yates: fixed