# Why aren't there any double quotes around taskname in task declaration in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, dsl

I read how we can omit parenthesis and dots to use groovy as a DSL. Due to which thought that `task` is a method.

But I'm confused if `task` is a method of the form `def task(String name, Closure closure)`. Then a task would be declared in DSL as `task "taskname", {}`. But actually, it is `task taskname {}`.

Why doesn't groovy misinterpret `taskname` as a variable name here? And if `task` is not a method what is it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature provided by the Gradle DSL. The token following `task` is turned into a `String` if it doesn't refer to another property. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803371