# Groovy syntax on Gradle task example

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm very enthusiastic about Groovy, but have just started using it very recently and would like to understand Gradle from language syntax POV as well.

My example is about Gradle task:

```
task hello(type: GreetingTask)

class GreetingTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def greet() {
        println 'hello from GreetingTask'
    }
}
```

`task` method accepts a String name and a Closure. How can `hello(type: GreetingTask)` be a String out of a sudden? If `type` is a named parameter, what does `GreetingTask` mean? Is it a shortcut for `GreetingTask.class`? How come `hello` function/closure returns a String?

Comment: Gradle build scripts are a DSL, not just pure groovy

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be groovy syntax compliant. Apart from what I'm asking about everything else make sense from groovy syntax POV so far.

Comment: I don't know what else to say...  Gradle build scripts are a DSL, not just pure groovy...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the groovy syntax in a gradle task definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584463/understanding-the-groovy-syntax-in-a-gradle-task-definition)

Comment: hello can be interpreted as String due to a compiler plugin gradle uses. See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264/

Answer (score 3):

As Tim pointed out gradle scripts are written in a specific DSL which is not pure groovy. When it comes to creating tasks [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.String)) you can see the methods that are used to create a task and under the hood they will be invoked to create the task. Of course under the hood this calls are delegated to [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html), but there's not need to call `project.tasks.task` because of [scopes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties) and mentioned DSL. Now, how it happens that the code you provided creates an instance of task? With [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer.java) transformer. I know that this answer if far from being sufficient, however hope it helps a bit ;)

`type: GreetingTask` is an instance of `Map` (it's equivalent of `[type: reetingTask]`) and, yes, in groovy `.class` can be omitted when a class is referred.