# Gradle task syntax: how is it explained from a Groovy perspective?

Tags: gradle, groovy, dsl

I'm having a hard time understanding how Gradle's Groovy DSL works.

Unfortunately Gradle is the main use-case for Groovy that I come across in my day to day work, and I've noticed that for many devs, their exposure to Groovy is strictly through Gradle. And that a majority of Gradle users have a very limited grasp of Groovy as a consequence.

In my limited understanding of Groovy, the following sintax `tokenA tokenB { tokenC }` where all tokens are not language keywords, `tokenA` would be a method that we are calling with arguments `tokenB` and the final argument is a closure. I would like to think I'm correct, but I know I'm wrong because there probably needs to be a comma after tokenB for that analysis to be correct.

I am by no means, as you can already tell, a Groovy dev, and I think using Gradle without learning the basics of Groovy is a bad thing to do, because it limits me from fully exploiting its capabilities. But my only viable option is to learn though examples without learning the theory unfortunately.

I did check out some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46318271/groovy-syntax-on-gradle-task-example) but no answers where clear or complete enough for me.

**TL;DR**

1. How are the tokens `task myTask { doLast {} }` interpreted in Groovy?
2. Does Gradle use a standard Groovy interpreter?
3. How is `myTask` interpreted as an identifier when there is `task` and not `def` or a type behind it?
4. If later in the file I added `myTask { dependsOn myOtherTask }` how does that get interpreted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe its all groovy and nothing special to gradle. Here's the groovy concepts you need to know.

1. If the last argument of a method is a closure, you can put the closure after the closing bracket for the method arguments.

```
class MyClass {
   void doStuff(String name, Closure c) {
      c.call()
   } 
} 

def o = new MyClass() 
o.doStuff('x') {
   println "hello" 
}
```

2. You can implement [method missing](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-create-dynamic-methods.html?m=1) on your object. If someone tries to call a method that doesn't exist you can do stuff

```
class MyClass {
    def methodMissing(String name, args) {
        println "You invoked ${name}(${args})" 
    }
} 
def o = new MyClass() {
   o.thisMethodDoesNotExist('foo')
}
```

3. You can [set the delegate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#setDelegate(java.lang.Object)) on a closure

```
class MyBean {
   void include(String pattern) {...} 
   void exclude(String pattern) {...} 
} 
class MyClass {
   private MyBean myBean = new MyBean() 
   void doStuff(Closure c) {
      c.setDelegate(myBean)
      c.call()
   } 
} 

def o = new MyClass() 
o.doStuff {
   include 'foo' 
   exclude 'bar' 
}
```

These 3 groovy features pretty much explain the "magic" behaviour going on in a gradle script that have java developers scratching their heads.

So, let's break down your snippet

```
task myTask(type:Foo) { 
   doLast {...} 
}
```

Let's add some brackets and also add the implicit project references. Let's also extract the closure into a variable

```
Closure c = { 
   doLast {...} 
}
project.task(project.myTask([type: Foo.class], c))
```

The `project.myTask(...)` method doesn't exist and the behavior is ultimately implemented via `methodMissing` functionality. Gradle will set the delegate on the closure to the task instance. So any methods in the closure will delegate to the newly created task.

Ultimately, here's what's logically called

```
Action<? extends Task> action = { task ->
   task.doLast {...} 
}
project.tasks.create('myTask', Foo.class, action)
```

See [TaskContainer.create(String, Class, Action)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#create-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-org.gradle.api.Action-)

Comment: Thank you for the very useful answer. I wasn't aware of delegates, and that can explain a lot of the magic. I still have one question though. What is the word `task` considered in `task myTask { ... }`, is it a type like `int` or `MyClass`, is it a method that is looked up in a delegate? How is it that we can name the task without quotes? How can we have such a syntax `task <identifier><arguments>`? Is such a construct standard Groovy? I can't figure out how to come up with such a DSL using only closures and delegates. Maybe the missing link is in the question I link to in my question?

Comment: Please re-read my breakdown. Its a method call on the project object. `project.task(project.myTask({ ... }))`

Answer (score 3):

(disclaimer, I am not a groovy developer)

When running a build (eg. `gradle clean`), the contents of the `build.gradle` are evaluated against a `Project` object (created by the Gradle runner); see the Javadoc at [API-Gradle Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html); also read the entire summary as it contains a lot information. In that page they clarify that:

> A project has 5 method 'scopes', which it searches for methods: The Project object itself ...  The build file ... extensions added to the project by the plugins ... **The tasks of the project** .. a method is added for each task, using the name of the task as the method name ...

`task myTask { }` should be equivalent to `project.task('myTask')`. It creates a new task called "myTask" and adds the task to the current project (see the Javadoc). Then, a property is added to the project object, so that it can be accessed as `project.myTask`. `doLast {..}` invokes the `doLast` method on that task object; see the Javadoc at [Task-doLast](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#doLast-org.gradle.api.Action-)

---

So for some of your points:

1. `project.task('myTask').doLast(..)` (maybe with more about closures in here)
2. it does (try building from github); but there is additional processing; the `build.gradle` file is "injected" in a Project instance before running the build. Plus a lot of other steps
3. `project.task('myTask')`
4. `project.myTask.dependsOn(project.myOtherTask)` (probably with an additional closure, or Action instance involved) . This is due to tasks being added to the project as properties.

---

Also note that explicit statements, like `project.myTask...` are valid and they can be used in the `build.gradle` script; but the are verbose so rarely used.