# The syntax of create a task in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

[this official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks) describes how to define a task in gradle，E.g:

```
task helloTask {
   println 'Hello World!'
}
```

it seems this code actually means a method call, which is [`Task task(String name, Closure configureClosure)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-).

Since this is a method call, `helloTask` shoule be parameter `name`, which is `String` type. So where is the `‘’` or `""`？

**ps.**

BTW, the parentheses looks different with standard groovy method call.

Comment: Groovy provides several syntactic features that can make calls look nicer. The above actually is a call of the mentioned method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret Gradle DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326264/how-to-interpret-gradle-dsl)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look something like this:

```
task mytask(group:'mygroup', description:"my own simple task") {

    println 'this will be executed on evaluate, so on _any_ task'

    doLast {
        println 'after all tasks are evaluated this will only executed if mytask is executed'
    }

}
```